# More straightforward means of doing this?

Tags: mips

This is a homework problem.  My code is giving the correct answer.  Writing out the solution like I did was terribly confusing and took me a while.  Is there a better way of coding this?

```
# Convert to MIPS: (((5 + 1) - (1 + 3) + (5 - 3)) - 1) – 5 + 3

main:
    li $t0 5
    li $t1 1
    li $t2 3
    #         (((5   + 1)   - (1   + 3)   + (5   - 3))   - 1)   – 5   + 3
    # becomes ((($t0 + $t1) - ($t1 + $t2) + ($t0 - $t2)) - $t1) - $t0 + $t2
    #         (((  $t3    ) - (  $t4    ) + (  $t5    )) - $t1) - $t0 + $t2

    add $t3, $t0, $t1
    add $t4, $t1, $t2
    sub $t5, $t0, $t2
    sub $t6, $t3, $t4
    add $t6, $t6, $t5
    sub $t6, $t6, $t1
    sub $t6, $t6, $t0
    add $a0, $t6, $t2

    li $v0, 1             # print $a0
    syscall

    li $v0, 10            # system call 10... lets us exit, load 10 in $v0
    syscall               # call the exit.
```

Comment: Are you using the SPIM emulator by chance?

Comment: I am using QtSpim.  My code is supposed to do a simple arithmetic problem.

Comment: For the above arithmetic, the parenthesis don't change anything except sign in 1 case.  You could just load your numbers (5,1,-1, -3, 5, 3, -1, -5, 3 into a RAM table and loop through reading a value, adding it to the total, then return the value when done.  Would take very few registers and be a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MIPS C compiler, you can always compile this with optimizations turned off:

```
int main()
{
    int one, three, five;
    int result;

    one = 1;
    three = 3;
    five = 5;

    result = (((five + one) - (one + three) + (five - three)) - one) -
        five + three;
    return result;
}
```

then run objdump on the resultant object code. It's not the way your professor wants you to do it, but you've already done that and you'll learn more.

**Edit**:

I usually run the C preprocessor on my assembly language files before passing them to the assembler. It can make things much easier to read, when particular registers are used for particular things:

```
#define FIVE  $t0
#define ONE   $t1
#define THREE $t2
#define FIVE_PLUS_ONE    $t3
#define ONE_PLUS_THREE   $t4
#define FIVE_MINUS_THREE $t5
#define ACCUM $t6

main:
    li FIVE 5
    li ONE 1
    li THREE 3
    //         (((5   + 1)   - (1   + 3)   + (5   - 3))   - 1)   – 5   + 3
    // becomes ((($t0 + $t1) - ($t1 + $t2) + ($t0 - $t2)) - $t1) - $t0 + $t2
    //         (((  $t3    ) - (  $t4    ) + (  $t5    )) - $t1) - $t0 + $t2

    add FIVE_PLUS_ONE, FIVE, ONE
    add ONE_PLUS_THREE, ONE, THREE
    sub FIVE_MINUS_THREE, FIVE, THREE
    sub ACCUM, FIVE_PLUS_ONE, ONE_PLUS_THREE
    add ACCUM, ACCUM, FIVE_MINUS_THREE
    sub ACCUM, ACCUM, ONE
    sub ACCUM, ACCUM, FIVE
    add $a0, ACCUM, THREE

    li $v0, 1             // print $a0
    syscall

    li $v0, 10            // system call 10... lets us exit, load 10 in $v0
    syscall               // call the exit.
```

Comment: You've already done your homework. Hand that in. This is a way to learn more about how computers do their things.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem commented in your code.

Yes, you can do it in a more straight forward way.  You just make a different section for each operation that happens in the order that they happen. but that would make your code longer, and not really that much more readable either

```
li $t0 5
li $t1 1
add $t2, $t0, $t1

li $t0 1
li $t1 3
add $t3, $t0, $t1

sub $t4, t2, t3


li $t0 5
li $t1 3
sub $t2, $t0, $t1

add $t3, $t4, $t2

li $t0 1
sub $t2, $t3, $t0
#etc.
```